# Orientdb slow performance for depth 3

Tags: heap-memory, orientdb, depth

I'm doing some traversal on graph with a dataset of 11M edges , 20000 nodes . 
Using OrientDB that is supposed ti be faster than Neo4j for depth , I'm seeing a slow performance.
The two queries used are :

```
TRAVERSE out("R") FROM #21:39161 MAXDEPTH 3 STRATEGY BREADTH_FIRST
```

And

```
traverse * from (select * from l where p='25440') while $depth<=3
```

The first query is returning 
this error

```
 [OServer]java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid3920.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [911684234 bytes in 26,730 secs]
```

While the second is taking forever loading for about half an hour.

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Hi, which version are you using? Thanks

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi I'm using 2.2.20 community versio n

Comment: Hi @Muna arr, can you try with a new version of orientdb?